# Dynamic web-page interface with persistent client changes

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

I am trying to create a web page with a tab menu. I want to be able to dynamically add and delete tabs (and other content). There is a perfect example of what I want here: http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/index.html?whichScript=tab-view . I want the newly created tabs to be persistent through page loads. So basically if I add a tab and refresh I want the tab to still be there. If I close the browser and reload the page a month later I would like the tab and any content to still be there. This page is for personal use and will be hosted on my computer and accessed through the browser alone, not any kind of web server. Although I'm not against using a web server if I need to.

Looking at the code it seems that the 'add tab' functions just add HTML to the page in memory but I need it to permanently change the HTML of the page. Is there a way to write dynamic changes to the DOM back to disk? I'm not quite sure where to go with this and searching for a week has left me with too many language and implementation options to look into. I am not an experienced web developer and there is so many different ways to create web pages and so many new terms that I'm a little overloaded now.

I do realize that this is a little outside the realm of a typical web-site. It is generally not a good idea to let the client-side make changes to data on the server-side. But since I am the only person who will be using this and it will not be accessible from the internet security is not an issue.

I'm not apposed to any particular scripting language, but I would like to keep it as simple as possible. I.e.: one HTML page, one CSS, and maybe a script file. Whatever is necessary. I am not apposed to reading and learning on my own either so being pointed down the right path is fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you need a rock solid method, then you would need some record of having those tabs existing. That means having a database that knows that the tab exists, which tab it was, and what content it contained. Html5's local browser storage (not to be confused with cookies though) could also be a viable solution but browser compatibility is an issue (for now).

You also need some sort of "user accounts system" so you know who among your users had this set of tabs open. Otherwise, if you had a single "tabs list" for everyone, everyone would open the same tabs!

For dynamic html and js for the "tab adding", you are on the right spot. You need PHP to interact with the database that is MySQL. What PHP does it it recieves data in the server from the browser about what happened like:

- know which user is logged in
- what action did he choose (add or remove tab)
- add to the database or delete a record
- reply with a success or error, whichever happened

For MySQL, you need to create a database with a table for your "tab list". This list must have:

1. User id (to know which user did what among the ones in the list)
2. Tab id (know which tab is which among the ones in the list)
3. Tab content (it may be a link for an iframe, actual html, text etc.)

Comment: I would be the sole user for this. My preferred browser is firefox. The purpose of this is for me to have a page where I can add my own links to internet web sites and local files, the abbility to add small comments and notes to the links. just an easy way for me to organize things im working on and I figured this would be easiest to implement and modify through a web page.

Comment: html, css and js do not have any method of local storage besides the new browser storage and cookies which have limitations. i suggest learning how php and mysql works as well as setting up a local web and database server with apache and mysql.

Answer (score 0):

Friend, when you talk of **closing the browser and not losing the data**, then you are talking about **data persistence** or **data durability**. In other words, you have to save your data somewhere, and load it next time.

For storage you can use a flat file (a simple text file), a database, an XML file, etc. However, you need to learn a lot to save the information and content of the new tab somewhere, and next time load it.

Comment: Is it not possible for an HTML page to edit its own HTML through a scripting language or something? All the 'add tab' code does is esentially add a new <div> and it seems to me that it could easily open the html document and add the <div> right to the local file as well.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. You can simply add a `<div>` element to your HTML document, which is generally known as **DOM manipulation**. But it's like editing a Word document, **without saving it**. Changes to DOM in browser are not **persistent**, that is, they get lost when you close the browser.

Comment: Yeah, I mentioned that in my original post. I would think there has to be a way to write DOM changes to disk. Setting up a SQL database and web server just seems like over-kill for what I am trying to accomplish. Maybe I could write the new <div> to a text file and load it to the DOM on page-load.

Comment: I found some information on http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtmlfile.php about saveHTML() and saveHTMLFile() that may just work. I will be looking into this.